# Strange hdd activity on windows 7

Tags: hard-drive

I noticed that I have very high hdd activity while I am not at my PC. When I am leaving my computer (not shutting down), after the screen turns off, the hdd starts to work immediately. What happens here? Is it some kind of defragmentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 7 Defragmentation Schedule default runs at 1:00 AM every weekly.

Windows 7 Search runs in background in a low priority and costs little resource with default configuration. But if you have used PC for a long time, you should care about Internet Explorer caching store.

I've never used Avast, so I guess you have to check your Avast Scanning Schedule or Scanning Rule.

Comment: I'll watch the avast stats when back at home.

Comment: It seems you are right, I'm not definitely sure about this, but I think its avast, performing scans on the hdd while the computer is not used.

Answer (score 1):

Probably disk defragmenting or anti-virus scanning.

Comment: Don't forget the Indexing Service!

Comment: Both possible, I use avast free antivir. Anybody there who knows for sure?

Comment: Only you can find out this.